# making listView acting like treeView in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, treeview

is there any way to make winforms listView showing data like treeView. i mean to make it verticaly oriented and to show columnHeaders one under another and not to put them in horizontal line?

thanx for assistance

Answer (score 3):

Consider using this open-source [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html).
It's a mature control that can show all sorts of lists, a tree-list and much much more (not my code - I'm just a happy user).

It take a few minutes to get used to the idea of using it, but once you got it - using it is a breeze.

Examples:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I enjoy using a well written piece of software. ObjectListView qualifies.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview). The usage is 99% same as the original .NET ListView, but it has many extras. For example, every item has a **ChildItems** property in which you can put further children.